# Keep javascript bundle file beautify using uglify

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs, rollup, rollupjs

I'm using `rollup-plugin-uglify` with rollup
I got development and production version of my JS bundle and I want on dev mode.
keep my file beautify though I'm using uglify

I tried to specified it as follows (on development build):

```
import uglify from 'rollup-plugin-uglify';

export default {
    entry: 'myfile.js',
    dest: 'mybundle.js',
    plugins: [uglify({
        beautify: true,
        mangle: false,
        compress:false
    })]
}
```

I'm using `rollup-plugin-uglify` with rollup
I got development and production version of my js bundle and I want on development mode
keep my file beautify though i'm using uglify

But unfortunately the file output still uglified.

Any idea?

Comment: how are you running this? Do you use any task runner?

Answer (score 2):

If you will look at uglify api https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/blob/master/README.md#api-reference, you'll see that 'beautify' option has 'output' namespace. Rollup plugin just directly passed options to uglify.